# ¿Como hago para que mis registros no sean el ultimo ingresado?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, lista

Tengo el problema de que, extraigo datos de un excel a una lista en memoria y luego los muestro en un DataGridView, pero al mostrarse todos los registros muestran el ultimo ingresado.
Por ejemplo, si el ultimo registro es Juan Diaz, todos los anteriores son Juan Diaz.
Lo que eh notado es que si concuerda con el numero de registros, pero no los datos.

No duden en corregirme, soy principiante en estos casos asi que leere sus respuestas detenidamente para aprender de ellas, Gracias por su atencion.

Aqui dejo el codigo.

```
private void btnProcesar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Valor> oListValor = new List<Valor>();
        Valor oValor = new Valor();
        try
        {
            if (strRutaFileName != "")
            {
                Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
                Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strRutaFileNameExcel);
                Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
                Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

                int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
                int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

                for (int i = 14; i < rowCount; i++)
                {
               
                    //var celda1 = xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value;
                    //var celda2 = xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 2].Value;
                    //var celda3 = xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 3].Value;
                    //var celda6 = xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 6].Value;

                    if (xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value != null && xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value != "")
                    {
                        oValor.Subitem = xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value.ToString();
                        oListValor.Add(oValor);
                    }
                    if (xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 2].Value != null && xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 2].Value != "")
                    {
                        oValor.NomSitem = xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value.ToString();
                        oListValor.Add(oValor);
                    }
                    if (xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 3].Value != null && xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 3].Value != "")
                    {
                        oValor.Consultor = xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 3].Value.ToString();
                        oListValor.Add(oValor);
                    }
                    if (xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 6].Value != null)
                    {
                        oValor.Horas = xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 6].Value.ToString();
                        oListValor.Add(oValor);
                    }
                }
                dgvExcel.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
                dgvExcel.DataSource = oListValor;

                MessageBox.Show("Complete");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Aqui dejo la clase:

```
 public class Valor
{
    public string Subitem { get; set; }
    public string NomSitem { get; set; }
    public string Consultor { get; set; }
    public string  Horas { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema radica simplemente en no entender el concepto de instancia de un objeto, y de como funciona agregar una instancia de un objeto a una lista.

Estas haciendo esto:

```
Valor oValor = new Valor();
```

Lo cual crea un una nueva instancia del objeto Valor dentro de la variable oValor (que en realidad es un puntero a una posicion de memoria que tiene el objeto).

Luego, dentro de tu for, haces esto (resumido):

```
if (xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value != null && xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value != "")
{
    oValor.Subitem = xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value.ToString();
    oListValor.Add(oValor);
}
```

que es: le agregas a la instacia oValor.Subitem un nuevo valor, y luego, lo agregas a la lista.. y aqui, es donde empiezan tus problemas....

porque, si es siempre la misma instancia, la cual estas llenando, la agregas hasta 4! veces en la lista? para mi, querias solo agregarla una vez, una vez que esta totalmente cargada.

Y luego, tu otro problema... oValor es siempre! el mismo objeto.. no cambia.. es siempre la misma posicion de memoria.. con lo cual, al llenar la lista, estas llenando la lista con el mismo objeto!!! y si este cambia de valor cambia en toda la lista, porque todas las posiciones de la lista apuntan a la misma instancia de objeto!!!

Entonces, hay que refactorizar tu codigo de la siguiente forma:

- hay que crear una instacia de objeto en cada vuelta
- hay que agregar el objeto a la lista, una vez que este todo cargado...

/

```
private void btnProcesar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    List<Valor> oListValor = new List<Valor>();
    // sacamos esto de aca -> Valor oValor = new Valor();
    try
    {
        if (strRutaFileName != "")
        {
            ...

            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

            for (int i = 14; i < rowCount; i++)
            {
                //Aca creamos las instancias, en cada vuelta
                Valor oValor = new Valor();
                if (xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value != null && xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value != "")
                {
                    oValor.Subitem = xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value.ToString();
                }
                if (xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 2].Value != null && xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 2].Value != "")
                {
                    oValor.NomSitem = xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 1].Value.ToString();
                }
                if (xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 3].Value != null && xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 3].Value != "")
                {
                    oValor.Consultor = xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 3].Value.ToString();
                }
                if (xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 6].Value != null)
                {
                    oValor.Horas = xlWorksheet.Cells[i, 6].Value.ToString();
                }
                oListValor.Add(oValor);
            }
            dgvExcel.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dgvExcel.DataSource = oListValor;

            MessageBox.Show("Complete");

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```